how to Print Image in unity webgl with javascript
Hello friends I have a project that I can't view with Unity on the webgl platform, now I want to print a photo that is in my project with a printer when I enter the project in Chrome for example and I click on the button, I want to know the javascript code How can it be and what should I do?
Unfortunately, you cannot use Windows codes to open the printer and print in C# Unity and webgl output.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp `JavaScript does not have any print object or print methods.
You cannot access output devices from JavaScript.
The only exception is that you can call the window.print() method in the browser to print the content of the current window. only thing I can imagine is you open the image as a new tap/window via [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and can then trigger a print()on that window instance .. note thatprint()` still only triggers your print dialog and you still have to interact in order to print of course
